# Regex to "double-count" Characters

Tags: python, regex, string

Given a string comprised of 0s, 1s, and 2s such as `'0010201'`: I would want an output which would be any series which is a one surrounded by any number (including zero) of 0s. In that case, the desired output would be `['0010', '01']`. Now, the code `re.findall("0*10*", "0010201")` will work correctly on that input. However, given part of the string which has a form like `1001` (two ones only separated by zeros), that regular expression will return `['100', '1']` when I would want it to return `['100', '001']` which would "double-count" the two middle 0s. How can I do this?

Comment: It's a good question, stated clearly and unambiguously, but the clause "which is a one surrounded by any number (including zero) of 0s." could be improved. I initially read the first part of that as "which is a one surrounded by any number (including zero)", though "0s" made clear what you meant. It's often easier to say what you want by being more specific: "I wish to extract each `1` together with all `0`'s that immediately precede and follow it".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a regex that matches overlapping matches, but you need to specify custom left-hand boundary: it must require a non-`0` char or start of string.

You may use

```
re.findall(r"(?=(?<!0)(0*10*))", text)
```

**Details**

- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead that allows overlapping matches:

  - `(?<!0)`  -  a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a `0`
  - `(0*10*)` - Capturing group 1 (the return value for `re.findall`): zero or more `0` chars, `1` and then again zero or more `0` chars
- `)` - end of the lookahead.

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/MNLUG23142):

```
import re
rx = r"(?=(?<!0)(0*10*))"
print(re.findall(rx, "0010201")) # => ['0010', '01']
print(re.findall(rx, "1001"))    # => ['100', '001']
```

Comment: Argh! Beat me to it :)

Comment: I assume it could instead be written `(?<!0)(?=(0*10*))`. Correct?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Jeez I really need to learn more about regular expressions

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is already stylistic as these are all zero-width assertions. Since the capturing group in a lookahead is the core of the pattern, the lookbehind that sets a custom boundary looks more natural to me also inside the lookahead.